# drawing a bmp from a panel saves an empty image c#

Tags: c#, panel, save-image

I am trying to draw a rectangle into a panel and then save this into a bitmap. the screen shows that I have been successful drawing the rectangles but when I view the saved bitmaps, they are empty white rectangles.

```
                System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;

                graphicsObj = panel1.CreateGraphics();

                Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1);
                System.Drawing.Rectangle myRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
            greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.MediumVioletRed);



                graphicsObj.FillRectangle(greenBrush, myRectangle);
                graphicsObj.DrawString("SomeString", new System.Drawing.Font
                ("Arial", 12), Brushes.Blue, myRectangle);

                graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);

                string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string img = t.Field<int>("ID").ToString() + ".png";
                string total = dir + "\\pics\\" + img;

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientRectangle.Width,
                panel1.ClientRectangle.Height);
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
                string dira = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string imga = t.Field<int>("ID").ToString() + "cal.bmp";
                string totala = dira + "\\pics\\" + imga;
                bmp.Save(totala);
```

Comment: DrawTobitmap calls the Paint event and will only draw things you draw there. Either move the drawing to Paint or draw to the Bitmap itself, using Graphics.CreateFromImage(bitmap). You could set the Panel.BackgroundImage to the Bitmap then or save it..

Comment: More generally: the code you posted is simply broken. You should only draw in the `Paint` event or `OnPaint()` override. If you find yourself calling `CreateGraphics()` you're almost always doing it wrong (and if you must, **make sure you dispose the `Graphics` object you created!**).

Comment: Well, if all he wants to achieve is an Image on disk, then drawing directly into a Bitmap is fine. Also if he needs no interaction or dynamics, like undo options. I would create a checkerboard background not in the paint event but by tiling a tiny Bitmap I create on the fly.. You are right about disposing the Graphics and also the Bitmap when done with it. The real question is: What is the big picture, where does he want to go next..?

Comment: thank you, hat was helpful.